# Firebase Deeplink not redirecting to app if select goo.gl

Tags: ios, firebase, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm integrating firebase in application. I created universal link that worked for Android & iOS both.

This worked great. BUT I got scenario where I clicked on **goo.gl** (PFA) link which was displaying on launched app right-top side. And from then no matter what I do, Deeplink will never launch my application.

[image]

I checked to clear history of device-browser but it's same. Any suggestion how to get rid of this issue/feature ??

Comment: Instead of just tapping the link in Hangouts, try long tapping and see if there is an "Open in MyApp" option in the menu that appears.

Comment: @deville not nothing there. Hangout using I'm as an source giving me **Copy** option only. Any other suggestion.

Comment: Try one of the native iOS apps: Notes, Safari, Messages etc.

Comment: How that is related with Solution of my question @deville ?

Comment: Third-party apps may not contain the "Open in MyApp" option when you long tap the link. Apple's own apps usually do.

Comment: OK, How can enable this feature ? Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 5):

You're absolutely right: the forward button is *horrible* UI/UX. It's one of the big flaws with Universal Links identified in [this blog post](https://blog.branch.io/apples-universal-links-a-testament-to-untested-software). There is no way to disable the forward button, and once it's triggered, you're screwed.

The easiest way to re-enable Universal Linking behavior after it is turned off is to long-press on the link. Your best bet at getting a clean shot is to paste the Universal Link URL into the stock Notes app and try long-pressing it from there.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'm testing with Hangout and there if I do long press then it simply me display Copy option :) . But other then I checked with Linkedin app & interestingly they have some solution. For same thing after redirect app to Web Browser it redirect control to app. Any suggestion what's this feature ?

Comment: I haven't seen that behavior with LinkedIn and can't replicate it. If you have Chrome installed and clicking the link inside Hangouts, possibly they are using a URI scheme redirect to launch the app — this is one of the few edge cases where URI schemes are still useful

Comment: URI Schemes, seems interesting. Any idea how to induced it in Deep link URL. I'm using firebase to generate Deeplink.

Comment: No way with Firebase unfortunately. They would have to add that custom handling for Chrome to their system, and they have not done so. We had to specifically identify that edge case at [Branch.io](https://branch.io) and write special code for it, but it could break at any time due to a Chrome update

Comment: Thanks, I checked with Firebase param **ius = schemes** and this has solution at certain level. So when it redirect to web page it ask you to open it in App-Store, just cancel it Pull Browser page little. It will give you option to jump to install App directly. But still not sure how Linked-in doing this without doing all these?

Answer (score 0):

Long hold on the url and there will be option to open in app.

Comment: I checked with that, but long press on Hangout I'm using as an source, give me Copy option :). Any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you click the "forward" link to open the universal link in Safari, you can re-open the app by dragging the page down. A bar will appear with your app name and an "OPEN" button. This works as long as you're still in the same URL.

Unfortunately, for Firebase Dynamic Links specifically, the link will redirect you to another domain (for example, from `https://z99zz.app.goo.gl/zzzz` to `https://z99zz-c.app.goo.gl/zzzz`) and this breaks this feature. The solution is to either add `?d=1` to the original link (`https://z99zz.app.goo.gl/zzzz?d=1`, opens a link debug page), or just remove everything after the domain (`https://z99zz.app.goo.gl/`, opens an error page). Now when it opens in Safari, you can drag down and see the bar.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **imgx64** post. I had a similar problem: Firebase redirected to **z99zz-c.app.goo.gl/zzzz** and in this case system was not redirected to my app. I added "applinks:mzn3g-c.app.goo.gl" as Associated domain in my target capabilities and this does the trick! Even if you redirected to domain with "-c" suffix iOS can recognize it and will redirect to your app and show suggestion in Safari